# Tips for developing a LCD display emulator

Tags: embedded, emulation, lcd, hd44780

I'd like to develop a PC LCD display emulator for educational purposes. The display uses HD44780.

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not actually answering your question but it might be of interest:

[Dincer's JavaScript LCD Simulator V 1.06](http://www.dinceraydin.com/djlcdsim/djlcdsim.html)

Comment: Good find. There is also a link to the source: http://www.dinceraydin.com/djlcdsim/djlcdsim1.zip